# C# MySQL SQL update/insert

Tags: c#, mysql

Can someone tell me what is wrong in this SQL syntax?

This is to update and if not insert, I'm using C#

This is my error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(spawn_1x = '1', spawn_1y = '4', spawn_1z = '4') where id ='1' if @@ROWCOUNT=0 i' at line 1

And this is my C# code:

```
public static void mudarspawn1(float x, float y, float z)
{
    string sql = "update spawnposition1 set (spawn_1x = '" + x + "', spawn_1y = '" + y + "', spawn_1z = '" + z + "') where id ='1' if @@ROWCOUNT=0 insert into spawnposition1 (spawn_1x, spawn_1y, spawn_1z) values ('" + x + "', '" + y + "', '" + z + "')";

    try
    {
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(cs);
        conn.Open();

        MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
        cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(MySqlException e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
    }
}
```

Any tips?

Comment: Can you include the full SQL statement that you trying to execute?

Comment: Does @@ROWCOUNT even exist in MySql? I'm fairly sure that's a TSQL concept

Comment: Yea I can see it is the value of the sql string variable, unfortunately I don't have your complete source code in an IDE. Could you help us out by including the exact and complete SQL statement that is causing the error?

Comment: well, i think is just that statement.. i tried just a insert and its working all vars are working, but then i tried to use the update and insert at the same time, i dont know what to show you more, maby the function that sends the data

Comment: I'm not sure how else I can say it... The problem you are having is invalid SQL syntax. Can you include in your question, the exact SQL that it is trying to execute?

Comment: im trying to execute this:
`"update spawnposition1 set (spawn_1x = '" + x + "', spawn_1y = '" + y + "', spawn_1z = '" + z + "') where id ='1' if @@ROWCOUNT=0 insert into spawnposition1 (spawn_1x, spawn_1y, spawn_1z) values ('" + x + "', '" + y + "', '" + z + "')";`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First remove the parenthesis in the update

```
string sql = "update spawnposition1 set spawn_1x = ...";
```

Next, NEVER concatenate your query like that. Use parameters. You're converting floats to string, so your code will only work if the decimal separator on you sql server and app server is the same.

Then check if you can use `@@ROWCOUNT` in mysql. I think you should use `ROW_COUNT()`

That should be enough.

Comment: Thank you, its fixed, i just removed the parenthesis in the update and used parameters

Answer (score 0):

The key to solving this problem, which I solve often because I make lots of mistakes in my sql creation is to take the value of sql (from the debugger), and attempt to execute that string in the MySQL equivalent of SQL Management Studio.

Without being able to see your tables, I had to make some guesses, but here is some code that works:

```
create table #T
(
    EventID int, 
    testX varchar(30),
    testY varchar(30)
)
insert into #T (EventID, testX) values (1, 'z')
update #T set testX = 'y', testY = 'A' where EventID = '2' if @@ROWCOUNT=0 insert into #T (EventID, testX, testY) values (2, 'A', 'B') 
select * from #T

drop table #T
```

You will notice that in my update, there are no parenthesis, which might be your problem.